# unable to launch SQLDevelper 20.4.0.379

Tags: java, jvm, oracle-sqldeveloper, java-11, msvcr100.dll

Im having this error when i try to launch sqldeveloper :  " unable to launch the java virtual machine locate at path: ERROR: ca,t find msvcr100.dll or msvcp140.dll "

java home is configured (i'm  using JDK 11.0.9)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wPJi.png)

Comment: Find a copy of that dll file and put it in your jdk/bin folder

Comment: That's right copy msvcr100.dll and msvcp140.dll from previous JDK and it should help: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4339484/unable-to-launch-the-java-virtual-machine-msvcr100-dll-with-jdk-1-8u261

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to download latest version :

https://www.oracle.com/database/sqldeveloper/technologies/download/